# How to copy a sheet in one workbook and paste just the values in a new workbook?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel workbook that has quite a few formulas, and when I try to upload the workbook into a database, the cells with iferror formulas come in as blanks even though it should be a string or number.  I am new to python but I want to create a python file that will read in the sheet, and paste only the values into a new workbook.

I tried:

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb1 = xl.load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1["Sheet 1"]


wb2 = xl.load_workbook('file2.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.create_sheet(ws1.title)

for row in ws1:
   for cell in row:
        ws2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value

wb2.save('path')
```

The code works to copy the data into a new workbook, but it is pasting the formulas.  I just want the values.

Comment: Would this help? `wb = xl.load_workbook('file1.xlsx', data_only=True)`?

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my earlier comment:

This comes from the [OpenPyxl docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html):

Where it's stated on the `openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook` submodule, looking at the `data_only` parameter:

- *data_only (bool) – controls whether cells with formulae have either the formula (default) or the value stored the last time Excel read the sheet*

Default is `Formulas` whereas you want the values. So setting it to true:

```
wb = xl.load_workbook('file1.xlsx', data_only=True)
```

Should help :)

[image]